# Auth::guard('admin')->user() is NULL in laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel-5

I'm trying to return the user logged in but I'm getting null 
when I dd(Auth::guard('admin')->user() in the login Controller it works but when I try to use it in NiveauController it returns null.

LoginController:

```
public function VerifierLogin(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, [
        'email'   => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:6'
    ]);

    if (Auth::guard('enseignant')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->get('remember'))) {
        Auth::guard('enseignant')->user();

        return redirect()->intended(route('EnseignantDashboard'));
    }
    if (Auth::guard('superadmin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->get('remember'))) {
        Auth::guard('superadmin')->user();

        return redirect()->intended('/superadmin');

    }
    if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->get('remember'))) {
        Auth::guard('admin')->user();

        return redirect()->intended('/admin');
    }

    return back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))->with('error');
     }
```

NiveauController:

```
 public function showListNiveaux()
{


    $admin=Auth::guard('admin')->user();

    dd( $admin);

   $niveaux = DB::table('niveaux')->where('id_etablissement',$admin->id_etablissement);

    return view('Niveau:index',compact($niveaux));
}
```

Comment: Do you only get this error for the `admin` guard or for all of them? Also make sure you are using the `auth` middleware.

Comment: I get this error for all the guards

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens if you forget to put the `auth` middleware on your route/controller

Try putting this in your controller

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        //OR
        // $this->middleware('web');
    }
```

and see if this solves your issue.